# EXC_BAD_ACCESS reloading cell with textfield inside

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicollectionview, exc-bad-access, uicollectionreusableview

I have a problem in my app and can t find a solution.

I have a **UICollectionView** with custom cells. My cells have a UITextField inside.

When textfield is in editMode (with the keyboard active), if i reload the collectionView i have a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error. This error happen because the call of the method **resignFirstResponder** of the **UITextField**.
The problem is the cell probably don´t exist anymore inside the collectionView, since it was dealloced.

This is my stack on the error:

[image]

Any idea how to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your custom cell deconstructor properly disposing of all observers?

Comment: can you explain better your question @cdstamper, i only add the resignFirstResponder in the "textFieldShouldReturn"

Comment: Can you show me the trace? It sounds like your dealloc isn't doing what it should. Perhaps your UITextField delegate ceases to exist at some point - in which case, you should be setting it to nil when your object disappears.

Comment: i just updated my question. where should i set the object to nil? in the deadlock of the custom cell?  The delegation of the textfield is outside the custom cell scope, in the model witch feed the cell

Comment: Typically you would do this in your dealloc method (commonly know as the deconstructor). Since the textField is owned by your custom cell, but the delegate is outside of your cell's scope...try setting delegate=nil in your cell's dealloc.

Comment: Still the same. I add a breakpoint insiste the dealloc and the method is never called... Strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference in the model to the textfield, weak reference.

When the model will be dealloc, resign the responder of the textfield.

Code:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    if (self.refrenceTextField) {
        [self.refrenceTextField resignFirstResponder];
        self.refrenceTextField = nil;
    }
}
```